# Alternative to BugSense for Windows Phone

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, bugsense

It seems that BugSense is abandoned for Windows Phone. I still see the statistics in my dashboard, but can't find SDK for Windows Phone in [docs](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/MINTMgmtConsole/latest/UserGuide/AboutSplunkMINTManagementConsole)(thats why i thought that BugSense for windows is closed).

Are there any good alternative for viewing error/trace reportings with some dashbord, showing internal information without needing me to mark it for logging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd encourage you to check out Crittercism. It's actively being developed and supported (last update was about a week ago):

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Crittercism
>
> http://docs.crittercism.com/windows/windows.html

Comment: Thanks! Seems the thing i was searching for.